# QuickSharp - set floating form size

Tags: c#, docking, dockpanel

Using the *[QuickSharp SDK](http://quicksharp.sourceforge.net/doc_extending_the_user_interface.php)*, how do you manage the size of a window if it is floating?

I want to set the `MinimumSize` for a floating panel that is created when a plugin is loaded.

QuickSharp uses the WeifenLuo DockPanel Suite, and [there is a way to manage the windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674266/using-weifenluo-dockpanel-suite?rq=1) with that, but it isn't so obvious how to use this code with QuickSharp because QuickSharp creates its own docking classes from the underlying WeifenLuo library.  Sure, you can sniff it out via the source code, but there is a lot of information there, and it is rather advanced.

[Here is another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502759/weifenluo-dock-panel-suite-float-windows-using-their-design-size?rq=1) about managing floated windows.